# Ajax Post to Controller 404

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ajax call posting to a controller.

When I click on a sell button a prompt allows the user to type in the name of a game they want to sell, which is saved in the Video Game Store database.

When the SellFunction is called, however, I'm getting a 404 error.

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
function SellFunction() {
var name = prompt('Please enter the game you are selling us:');
alert("Thank you for your business!");

var RandomID = Math.random
RandomID *= 20;
Math.floor(RandomID);

var GameObject = {VideoID: RandomID, Price: 20, Name: name } //now we have to basically just send something easy

//ajax post store name in video game model for the store
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(GameObject),
    url: "index/videogamesale",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response.success) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        } else {
            // DoSomethingElse()
            alert(response.responseText);
        } 
    }

});
```

}

This is the error I am getting:
[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAcOT.png)

Here is my controller Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace VideoGameStore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VideoGameSale(VideoGame newgame)
        {
            using (var db = new VideoGameModel())
            {

                db.Games.Add(newgame);
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var VideoGame in db.Games)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(VideoGame.Name);
                }

               return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your 
               message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the VideoGame Model Code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace VideoGameStore
{
    public class VideoGameModel : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VideoGame> Games { get; set; }
    }

    public class VideoGame
    {
        public int VideoID { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the table:[dbo.VideoTD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EigWC.png)

I've searched the web, but the problem remains as elusive as ever. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, someone forgot to tell MVC that `index/videogamesale` maps to `HomeController.VideoGameSale`.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. Not so elusive after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should change ajax request to this and it'll work out perfectly

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(GameObject),
    url: "Home/VideoGameSale",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response.success) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        } else {
            // DoSomethingElse()
            alert(response.responseText);
        } 
    }});
```

And router will map it to Controller Home and action VideoGameSale. And since your action VideoGameSale expects a HTTPPOST request it'll work out cause of method: "POST" statement.

Comment: Thanks a million! Ah, Still getting used to the common mistakes as a new MVC programmer....Now the post is working properly