# Button click works locally, but not in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**I followed the steps in the potentially duplicate question, and it did not resolve my error.**

My entire application works properly when uploading to the server, except for one button.

The button is a simple button with an ID.  When I click it, a function catches the click, grabs the associated data from the user entry fields, sends it to the controller, and the data is saved to the database.

When I upload to the server, everything else on the website works perfectly. That one button, however, throws a 404 error when trying to find the controller action.

Here is the button:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

The script that calls the controller action:

```
$(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            //snipped for brevity

                //Send the records to server for saving to database.
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: "/Designees/InsertDesg",
                    data: '{FnameD: "' + txtFnameD.val() + '",LnameD: "' + txtLnameD.val() + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:  function (r) {
                        $("#txtLandownerID").val(r.LandownerID);
                        $("#txtPermitNo").val(r.PermitNo);
                        $("#txtExpYear").val(r.ExpYear);
                    //Add the Name value to first cell.
                    SetValue(row, 2, txtFnameD);
                    SetValue(row, 3, txtLnameD);

                    //Add the row to the WebGrid.
                    webGrid.append(row);
                    window.location.href = r.Url;
                    }

                });



            });
```

The controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult InsertDesg(Designee designee)
        {
            designee.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            designee.ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.BhCode == User.Identity.Name);
            designee.EnteredBy = user.Id;
            db.Designees.Add(designee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Designees", new { id = designee.LandownerID, permit = designee.PermitNo, year = designee.ExpYear });
            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl, designee });
        }
```

My local results:
[image]
[image]

My server results:
[image]

I would expect the same thing to happen on the server as happens on my local system. Can anyone think of a solution?  My IIS logs don't show anything but the 404 error.

**SOLUTION**

I have no idea why this fixed it, but I changed my function call from the above to the below, and it is now working properly:

```
 var RootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';

                //Send the records to server for saving to database.
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: RootUrl + "Designees/InsertDesg",
```

Comment: can you try to give full path in url  instead of this url: `"/Designees/InsertDesg"` to `http://your_path/Designees/InsertDesg`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax Post to Controller 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964276/ajax-post-to-controller-404)

Comment: @NoumanZakir The post you linked does not resolve my problem; I've already seen it.

Comment: @Carthax or just try URL without`/`  ` "Designees/InsertDesg"`

Comment: Try putting "../Designees/InsertDesg" or "~/Designees/InsertDesg" or "./Designees/InsertDesg" instead your URL. Depending on how the server is set up, this might help.

Comment: @MangeshAuti, you have my many thanks for your suggestions which led me to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to create the ajax url link using `Url.Action()`.

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        //snipped for brevity

            //Send the records to server for saving to database.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("InsertDesg", "Designees")",
                data: '{FnameD: "' + txtFnameD.val() + '",LnameD: "' + txtLnameD.val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success:  function (r) {
                    $("#txtLandownerID").val(r.LandownerID);
                    $("#txtPermitNo").val(r.PermitNo);
                    $("#txtExpYear").val(r.ExpYear);
                //Add the Name value to first cell.
                SetValue(row, 2, txtFnameD);
                SetValue(row, 3, txtLnameD);

                //Add the row to the WebGrid.
                webGrid.append(row);
                window.location.href = r.Url;
            }

        });



    });
```

This way you don't have to worry about assigning the `RootUrl` variable like the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting this code in your action and see if it works:

```
[HttpPost("Designees/InsertDesg", Order = 1)]
public JsonResult InsertDesg([FromBody]Designee designee)
```